# How to create i help button in Rails

Tags: html, css, jquery-dialog

May be for you guys is obvious but for me is not.

I would like to create an `i` help image, that when it is clicked it pop ups a window with information.

I have tried something like this but it does not help:

```
<a id="dialog-1" href="#"><button id="opener" >i</button></a>

<script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
           autoOpen: false,  
        });
        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
           $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
     });
</script>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: what errors you have?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: Are you copying the `.dialog` stuff off a web page somewhere?  If so then that page will tell you that you need to include one or more javascript files in your layout/page in order to use it.

Comment: Did you include the library `jquery-ui`?

Comment: You can't have a button inside an anchor. Use a validator: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: It was missing to add the library. thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from my comments

> Did you include the library `jquery-ui`?

include the `jquery-ui` library in your application.js  file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to accomplish what you need. 
I will make a suggestion, there are probably other ways but this is something simple.

For the "i" image, I recommend you getting an actual image, better a png with transparent background. 
Another option is using an iconic font, such as Font Awesome ([example](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/info-circle/)). It looks like an image, but it is treated like a font, so you can change the color, size, etc.

For the pop-up. Single option is creating a hidden div with absolute positioning and opening it with javascript/jQuery and maybe fading the background a little bit. You can google it a little bit and will find many solutions, one will fit your need for sure.

As a second improvement: If the content is very heavy, you may want to load it on demand via AJAX or other async ways, but first get the info window working :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you miss the `$( document ).ready(function() { ... });`

try with this:

```
<a id="dialog-1" href="#"><button id="opener" >i</button></a>

<script>
     $(function() {
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
               autoOpen: false,  
            });
            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
               $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
         });
     });
</script>
```